# Vertical alignment of canvas text

Tags: javascript, canvas

I am working on a canvas based app, and I have some problems with the vertical alignment of my texts. I am using floating point coordinates, which I think are the cause of the problem. I am not sure though, and am nonetheless looking for a solution. Anyway, the code I use for displaying the letter 'O' in a square, for instance, is:

```
context.fillRect(0, 0, 21.864951768488744, 21.864951768488744);
context.textBaseline = 'middle';
context.textAlign = alignLeft ? 'left' : 'center';
context.fillText('O', 10.932475884244372, 10.932475884244372);
```

The result on the canvas is that the 'O' is centered horizontally, but placed about 1 - 2 pixels above the center.

Does anyone have any thoughts on this?

Comment: Could potentially be that the font isn't actually naturally central, which font are you using? Some fonts can display in noticeably different positions on different systems (Which is incredibly annoying at times)

Comment: I am using Arial..

Comment: Vertical alignment refers to the font's baseline. Each individual character is not vertically centered -- or you would see dipping & rising characters of text. The capital "O", being a tall character, is likely to extend higher vertically than shorter characters of the same font.

Comment: This does make sense, but when I draw larger characters I feel that I don't see this misalignment.

Comment: On further inspection I see that the misalignment remains 1 - 2 pixels when using larger fonts, it is simply not clearly visible. This means that the misalignment does not seem to scale which makes my original hypothesis (some sort of rounding error for floating coordinates) would still still make sense. As I explained in my other comment, adding a dipping character places the text 1 - 2 pixels below the center..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that there indeed is a problem with floating coordinates when writing texts. As the example - http://codepen.io/petor/pen/NRPgVq - clearly shows texts cannot be displayed on subpixel coordinates and will be placed on rounded coordinates (at least on Chrome).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="200" height="100" style="border:1px solid #000000;">
Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.
</canvas>
<script>
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var context= c.getContext("2d");;
context.font = "10px Arial";
context.fillText('O', 0, 10);
context.fillText('O', 10, 10.1);
context.fillText('O', 20, 10.2);
context.fillText('O', 30, 10.3);
context.fillText('O', 40, 10.4);
context.fillText('O', 50, 10.5);
context.fillText('O', 60, 10.6);
context.fillText('O', 70, 10.7);
context.fillText('O', 80, 10.8);
context.fillText('O', 90, 10.9);
context.fillText('O', 100, 11);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 11):

It's leaving space for characters with descenders. Add something with a descender like a "y" to see what I mean.

```js
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var context= c.getContext("2d");
context.fillStyle = "#FF0000";
context.fillRect(0, 0, 21.864951768488744, 21.864951768488744);
context.font = "10px Arial";
context.fillStyle = "#FFffff";
context.textBaseline = 'middle';
context.textAlign = 'center';
context.fillText('Oy', 10.932475884244372, 10.932475884244372);
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="200" height="100" style="border:1px solid #000000;">
Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.
</canvas>
```

Comment: Although it seems to be something like this, when I write the text 'Oy', the text is not exactly centered either. In the example you are giving, the text is placed 1 pixel below the center.. And as I also mentioned in my other comment, the displacement is still 1 -2 pixels when using larger characters, so the misalignment does not scale. So to me it still looks more like some sort of a rounding problem than something with descenders.

Comment: On the other hand, the O in the text 'Oy' is positioned at the same y coordinate as in the text 'O'. There is definitely space left over for descenders, but knowing this does not gain me more insight in how to solve the 1 - 2 pixels misalignment. The text is simply not (exactly) centered..